# Access arraylist from model in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
import java.io.Serializable

class Restaurant(var resId : Int , var resName : String , var image : String , var locationName : String , var longitude : String , var email : String , var latittude : String, menu : ArrayList<Menu> , phone : List<String>) : Serializable
```

How do you access this the array list of the menu

```
import java.io.Serializable
import java.util.ArrayList

open class Menu(var foodId : Int , var foodname: String ,var foodtype: String , var price: Int , var fooddetail: String ,var foodpicture: String ,var foodquantity: Int , var restuarantName: String , var foodCategory: ArrayList<FoodCategory>) : Serializable
```

This is the adapter class where I have forwared the code to:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val restaurant = restaurantList[position]
        holder.resName.text = restaurantList[position].resName
        Glide.with(context).load(restaurantList[position].image)
            .into(holder.resImage)
        holder.locationName.text = restaurantList[position].locationName
        holder.rlrestaurant.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(context, MenuActivity::class.java)
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putSerializable("restaurantMenu", restaurant)
            intent.putExtras(bundle)
            Log.i("Check","abc")
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

I am tryiig to access it in the menu activity as:

```
restaurant = intent.extras?.getSerializable("restaurantMenu") as? Restaurant
```

But doing this I cant access the menu arraylist 
All other properties are accessable except Menu and the phone.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to be much more specific of what you're asking. Also, use `code` blocks for your code.

Comment: yes sir my bad... I am not able to access the array list of the model in kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `var` or `val` at the beginning of `map` and `phone` parameters,

```
data class Restaurant(var resId : Int, var resName : String, var image : String, var locationName : String, var longitude : String, var email : String, var latittude : String, var menu : ArrayList<Menu>, var phone : List<String>) : Serializable
```

After that you will be able to access them,

```
val restaurant = intent.extras?.getSerializable("restaurantMenu") as? Restaurant
val map = restaurant.map
val phone = restaurant.phone
```